# How to relate one type to another type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have two types, say `Author` and `AuthorOpts`, that I want to "pair" together, such that whenever type inference infers that `Author` is the right type to use, I want to be able to grab/lookup `AuthorOpts` from that inferred generic.

(In other scenarios, I might create `AuthorOpts` has a mapped derivation of `Author`, i.e. `Opts<Author>`, but I can't/don't want to do that in this scenario.)

Currently I have a hacky way of doing this by adding a do-nothing field to `Author` that then I can pull back out with a `HasOpts` "lookup":

```js
interface Constructor<T> {
  new (): T;
}

class Author {
  firstName!: string;

  // This looks like a field but is used merely to look up the type
  __opts!: AuthorOpts;
}

type HasOpts<O> = { __opts: O };

interface AuthorOpts {
  firstNameFlag: boolean;
}

function find<T extends HasOpts<O>, O>(type: Constructor<T>, opts: O): void {}

find(Author, { firstNameFlag: true });
```

But I'd like to avoid the `Author.__opts` field if possible. Can I? Any better ways of doing this?

Comment: Is there anyplace in your code where `Author` and `AuthorOps` are "naturally" paired?  Without a structural dependence of `Author` on `AuthorOpts` I'm not sure what to do that won't look like a "hack" to you.  Is there a map somewhere of which things are paired?  Does `Author` have a method that takes an `AuthorOpts` argument?

Comment: I mean, is [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCCuAXAFgewE7QN4ChrQDMBLdCRAOTAFsBTAQgC5oz0iA7AcwG4cBfHHO0Q10BMMBpwkadAHkADohi58xUhWo0AYuA5MARqlQgaYNj345EAT3mSAsmHkwAvNADaNu6gJSUGABo-GQUlAF1oAB8PLxofaAARMGEgrGgAdzQAaTZUdIgmNngqfRFoXjCeAng2YEQiVDZCdgATAB57aBoAD2E2FphHZ3cABjCAPgAKWKZ7INRFAugAUV70cUQOpwgg9znoM2sJ9wBGMIBKJgA3VCIW7HKBYn7JhH90VOb1SlodMD1oIh0PBJLxzlVWpMkikHplUDk8ksTgAmADM5XBQA) a hack or a valid mapping?

Comment: > Does Author have a method that takes an AuthorOpts argument

Oh right, the constructor does. I didn't think of that has a field, and it's not on my "T extends Entity", but I think that's enough of a hint to get what I need.

How would the map approach work? Like I don't want a map of author instances to opt instance,s but like Author Type -> AuthorOpt Type, Book Type -> BookOpt Type. Maybe that's actually doable/easy but for some reason I'm not seeing it...

Comment: Ah wow, your "type Maps" is exactly what I was looking for. I think I'll try and get the constructor approach to work, b/c I should have thought of that, but I'm bookmarking playground that for future use. Thanks!

Comment: In retrospect, same as kaya3's answer, the map requires `find` to know ahead-of-time about this specific `Maps` definition, and I'm hoping to ship `find` generically and have the user "bring their own `Maps`" to the table just by passing `T`. Granted, I could put `find` in a class that is parameterized on `Maps`, but would be nice to avoid that.

Comment: I'm trying to get [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQGcxQK4JjpQA8AKgHzIDeAsAFDLIgQDuyAFBALYBcy6AEYArCIQA0AgA5gs-OCACeASn5kA3AwC+DBggA2cLFmQBBPGAAWxGgyYJMOfIWJc+AkWLCT0MuWYtrKAB5P2UaZB16O2QYYCgcADk4bggAQn4nUABzTXoohlBIWEQUcytiUNlbRlj4pJSIADFDbP5BdHR9CAU8gvoYPBBCYEw6kAATcklUZAgAD0hJkwxsXAIiUkoKDjBFKQh+VB8-fgAFOChG4qwSVAoAbQBGAF1VZAA3dGAJmn64yYccpBSTUOoJMDJVItOBtZDrFBaZR5IA) to work but not having luck.

Comment: [Got it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFxRMIgCUZEgQDcAWABQEzABsmSJFACC6YAAtcUAN4SoUTIhQZsuWhAC2XOACMAVhGwAaKHDDBOSletQB5V0gGaAL4SOlAAZgCWqCgAckxmEACEXIYRCKxi4sGS4mnAEKhhTJjQymq4vm5aoZHRwHEJAGKyrFxWcHDSEDyZ2RJh6AjYEYjhaQAmhE4wUBAAHvkI4wrwyGhYOPjERLSgkFwwTi5uBwbrxqgACizxEPnReDBEANoAjAC6fFwAbnAR41o+uJIktaGUvE5NGM6g0IM0mK0oOtoIE+JkgA) Thanks jcalz!

Comment: ...well [shoot](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gWAChllgATALmQGcwpQBzZAH2QFcQyIZQIyBuIgF8iRbAAcUAYQD2IWlDYIwMqAB4AKgD5kAXmQgIAd2QAKAHSW4UBtSpwQWAJR6dGwYSIIANnGrVkAEE2MAALVTwiEgQ5BSUVKFMIAFsqGQAjACsIZQAaZBlxMDsgkPCoAHki6hdcEWJSMgBCKgVGDxIeKFoAOThkiBaaOnbhUUJQSFhEFGCw1SriyIau3v6IADFfBip0mRlvCAcPeqIYDmVgOWQeTk1kCAAPSE4A9DBMLHypB+eIV+QsnkdHiqk0Wi0pgkECoUnyhWKsNiIOUqgACtZ1lNqGopFoANoARgAuk4qBpliQoBAwGwoCB2JxuLwyMg-GzHGyAu4xp5CDFgWy9DdQGRTHNyvlcCLumA+gMtnAdsgQSghE4PHBzKs5esPEQgA)

Comment: Consider editing your question code to be in keeping with these updated playground links, so that the question has a true [mcve] in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your class constructor is always going to take the "related type" as its second argument, as your Playground links imply, you should be able to type `find()` this way:

```
function find<T extends Entity, A>(type: new (a0: any, a1: A) => T, opts: A): T {
  return null!; // impl here please
}
```

And we can test it:

```
const a = find(Author, { firstNameFlag: true });
a.firstName; // okay
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gWAChllgATALmQGcwpQBzZAH2QFcQyIZQIyBuIgF8iyIggA2catWQBBNmAAWAeyh5RyBCpC0obBGDUAKCAFsqKgEYArCIYA0yFQAcw1KguVqA8m+oAlHjIIsSkZACEVHqMgmE8ULQAcnBmEFE0dLHCRESgkLCIKF6qUH7uGvHAiWApaQBiUgxUVioqEhBwIHGhRDAchsA6yDycADwAKsgQAB6QnLLoYJhYTnIAfMbYLhBUIBAA7sjGcAAMVF2ryHAAjJ5BALzryBNOru73VFMEYVAQYGwoCB2JxuLwyNdZJdIS8erlCNpdGBrsgHiNQGRjCU1E5cOianUII04M1kHQ2CghAE4nAAHQJZKpCBxIhAA)

Comment: Thank you! Inlining the constructor type for the `type` parameter makes a lot of sense; I was stuck on wanting to use the usual `Constructor<T>` type alias that was more generic than it needed to be.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are multiple classes that `T` can take which each have their own type for `opts`, either you have to define the each class's `opts` type within that class, or you define the `opts` types for every class all in one place.

Your question includes code for defining the `opts` type within the class, so here's an example of how you could define a mapping all in one place, using a conditional type:

```js
type OptsFor<T>
    = T extends Author ? { firstNameFlag: boolean }
    : T extends Foo ? { foo: number }
    : T extends Bar ? { bar: string }
    : never;

function find<T>(type: Constructor<T>, opts: OptsFor<T>): void {}
```

Comment: this looks interesting, although in this case I want `find<T>` to be defined in an npm library that I ship, and then for the user's project to have their own `OptsFor` defined, which `find` can then somehow "lookup" from the given `type` argument. I.e. I want to navigate from `T`/`Constructor<T>` to either `AuthorOpts` directly or an `OptsFor` map like you've defined.

Comment: In that case the way you've done it in your question seems like the way to go.